# How to fix generic 'Upload Failed' Message in Internal App Sharing?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I have been trying to implement dynamic delivery into my app using app bundles. I think I have successfully written an implementation as I can build my project and create the bundle. The app works fine if I create an apk including all modules, but I know the only way to test dynamic delivery is through internal app sharing.

I tested uploading bundles of my app without dynamic delivery and they upload fine, so I think it must be specific to this feature. However, when I upload my bundle with the dynamic modules, it always gets to the point where it lets me give the bundle a name and then it says "Upload Failed"

The error is so generic that I really can't pinpoint what's happening. Has anyone experienced this error / could provide some insight on where to look?

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw8RT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. I was mistakenly providing a signing configuration for my build.gradle in the dynamic module. This should only be done for the base module.

Answer (score 0):

One way to diagnose this is to upload the app bundle to the *internal test track* instead. While you'll get the same "Upload failed" error message, it may also give more information about the error.

Example:

[image: example error message]

In this case, the error was due to having `dist:onDemand` attribute and `<dist:delivery>` settings at the same time.